Tools to Identify Calling Convention Assembly Code or VEX IR Statements in Binary Files
I'm currently working on a project that involves analyzing binary files, and I need to identify and extract all the assembly code related to calling conventions. Specifically, I am looking for tools that can:

Detect assembly code involved in calling conventions (e.g., stack setup before a function call, stack cleanup after a function call) in binary files.
Identify VEX IR statements related to calling conventions.
I've been using tools like Valgrind and Angr, but I'm struggling to filter out the relevant VEX IR statements and assembly instructions specific to calling conventions.
Locate and analyze function prologues and epilogues in binary files.

Can anyone recommend tools or methods that can assist in this type of analysis? Any advice or examples of how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
I have already tried using angr.analyses.complete_calling_conventions and angr.calling_conventions in the Angr framework. However, I couldn't find any method that leads to the exact calling convention instructions. I expected these methods to help filter out the relevant VEX IR statements and assembly instructions specific to calling conventions, but they did not provide the desired results.
